# cmdでjavac -versionと入力しても何も表示されなくて困っています。

Tags: java, windows

これからプログラミングを勉強しようとしているものです。
Open JDKを使用して学習を始めようとしているのですが、設定確認のため cmd でバージョンを確認する作業をしても表示されず困っております。
JDKのファイルはダウンロードした後に「C:」に展開しております。

環境変数は
変数名は「JAVA_HOME」
変数値はフォルダーの参照より「C:¥jdk-15」
環境変数（PATH）も参照より「C:¥jdk-15¥bin」
を設定しております。

以上の設定を行った上で cmd から確認しようとして `javac -version` を入力して Enter を押すと

```
C:\Users\×××××> javac -version
C:\Users\×××××>
```

となってしまいます。
原因がわからず学習に進めません。お詳しい方がいましたらご教授いただきたく願います。

Comment: `C:\jdk-15\bin` の下に `javac.exe` は存在しますか？また、`C:\jdk-15\bin\javac -version` の様にフルパスで指定するとどうなるでしょうか？

Comment: @cubick　様　フルパスで入力したところ正常に表示されました。購入したテキストの通りに勧めたいのですが今後もフルパスで入力しなければいけないのでしょうか？

Comment: 念のため Windows を再起動した後に確認するとどうなるでしょうか？

Comment: [この回答](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19783549)を読みますと、JDK1.4 以前では javac コマンドに `-version` オプションが無かった様です。もしかすると、JDK1.4 以前が別のパスにインストールされていて、PATH でそちらを先に指定しているのかもしれませんね。

Comment: @cubick　様　再起動したのですが、フルパスでは表示されますが質問のように入力するとダメでした。C:¥jdk-15¥binの下にjavac.exeというのはフォルダーの中に存在するということでしょうか？パソコンにもあまり知識がなく理解力が低く申し訳ございません。

Comment: @metropolis　様　JDK1.4以前が別のパスにインストールされている場合、どのように検索したらよいのでしょうか？

Comment: @トルネコ PATH の内容に `jdk-1.4\bin` などのパスが含まれていないかどうかを確認してみてください。もしくは `cmd.exe`(コマンドプロンプト) で `where.exe javac` を実行して下さい。

Comment: @metropolis　様　確認してみましたがjdk-1.4\binまたは類似する数値はありませんでした。

Comment: @トルネコ `where.exe javac` の実行結果はどうなりますか？

Comment: @metropolis 　様　実行結果はC:\Users\81706>where.exe javac
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\javac.exe
C:\jdk-15\bin\javac.exeになりました。

Comment: @トルネコ そうなりますと、`C:\jdk-15\bin\javac.exe` ではなくて `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\javac.exe` の方が実行されていますね。

Comment: @metropolis 　様　ということはシステム変数にあるC:¥Program Files¥Common Files¥Oracle¥Java¥javapath¥というものを削除すれば通常通りに使用できる可能性はありますか？

Comment: はい、その通りです。

Comment: @metropolis 　様　該当箇所を削除したところ無事に教科書通りに表示されました！ありがとうございます。

Comment: コメントでのやり取りを踏まえて、「確認した内容」や「何をすれば直ったか」をぜひ自己回答の形で投稿してみてください。